# Populate one data extension from 5

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I have 5 data extensions with the same fields and i would like to join in one. Query would be the best method?  How i can applied a query that will get five data extensions? The fields above:

```
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes a Query would be the best method - you would utilize multiple Unions.

See below:

```
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_1]
UNION
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_2]
UNION
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_3]
UNION
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_4]
UNION
SELECT Name
       , LastName
       , Birth_date
       , Phone
       , Status
       , [HTML Emails]
       , [Email Address]
       , [AccountID] as [Subscriber Key]
       , [AccountID]
FROM [Query_DE_5]

/* Target: your_New_DE */
/* Action: Overwrite (or Update if you want to retain existing data in target) */
```

Answer (score 2):

As Gortonington suggests, you can accomplish this is SQL by using [**UNION** or **UNION ALL**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The **UNION** statement will remove duplicate rows that are returned, whereas **UNION ALL** will return all matching rows from each data extension.  Both are valid depending on your needs.